# Add value in specific rows

Tags: postgresql

I am newbie to sql, and this is my first time posting question here.

I created a table with 4 column. **Item** (which is Item no.) **Description** (the menu name) **unit_price** (price) and **Qty** (which is the order that has been made for that day).
I want the qty of every item so i write this query:

```
select distinct(Item),description,unit_price,qty
from cdsitem
order by item
```

but the problem is it doesn't add all the qty in the specific item, it looks like this.

[image: p1]

I want my output to become like this. the sum of quantity in every item no. and description

[image: p2]

I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Answer (score 0):

You want an aggregation query:

```sql
SELECT item, description, unit_price, SUM(qty) AS qty
FROM cdsitem
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Or use the more verbose version:

```sql
SELECT item, description, unit_price, SUM(qty) AS qty
FROM cdsitem
GROUP BY item, description, unit_price;
```

Comment: It works now. Thank you! can I ask what is 1,2,3 in group by?

Comment: @AngeloDejesus The `1`, `2`, and `3` refer to the first, second, and third columns of the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: I get the logic now. Thank you @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score -1):

select item,description,unit_price,sum(qty) as total_qty from cdsitem group by item;